# ElmahR Dashboard throws "Unable to compile template" error when Sending Commands

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah, elmahr

I worked through the Setup documentation found [here](https://bitbucket.org/wasp/elmahr/wiki/Setup).  I have a sample dashboard application and a sample client application which throws Elmah errors into a SQL database.

The client application has elmah working correctly and I can view the error logs at elmah.axd.  When I attempt to access the Dashboard application the page loads and kicks off the "Sending Commands" message.  I then get a 500 Internal Server error from the first "send?transport=..." command.

The Dashboard app is an ASP.Net MVC 5 app running on my localhost.

This is the URL that generates the error:

```
http://localhost/ElmahR/elmahr/commands/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=k6HUNtFtmSXrJZgH_2oexTg_cx-el2G7PhJ6NZD4aBLT_svpboE31meZG4wazu7VDS8_WWRjnnV-yGSVhBzBbYWlXFTo08onRvNCzYgYhH5kwMw9KvKOSQIakT6Wzv_Y0
```

When I inspect that error, this is what I get:

```
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException
Unable to compile template. Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\lahvjqh3.0.cs' could not be found Other compilation errors may have occurred. Check the Errors property for more information.

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException: Unable to compile template. Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\lahvjqh3.0.cs' could not be found

Other compilation errors may have occurred. Check the Errors property for more information.
   at RazorEngine.Compilation.DirectCompilerServiceBase.CompileType(TypeContext context) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Compilation\DirectCompilerServiceBase.cs:line 100
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplateType(String razorTemplate, Type modelType) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 256
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplate(String razorTemplate, Type templateType, Object model) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 127
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Parse(String razorTemplate, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag, String cacheName) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 435
   at ElmahR.Core.Plugins.<BuildPlugins>b__a(<>f__AnonymousType2`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier6)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ElmahR.Core.StartupConnection.<.ctor>b__1(IConnection c, IRequest r, String cid, String d)
   at ElmahR.Core.StartupConnection.OnReceived(IRequest request, String connectionId, String data)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.<>c__DisplayClassa.<>c__DisplayClassc.<ProcessRequest>b__7()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(Func`1 func)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallContextAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
---> (Inner Exception #0) RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException: Unable to compile template. Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\lahvjqh3.0.cs' could not be found

Other compilation errors may have occurred. Check the Errors property for more information.
   at RazorEngine.Compilation.DirectCompilerServiceBase.CompileType(TypeContext context) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Compilation\DirectCompilerServiceBase.cs:line 100
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplateType(String razorTemplate, Type modelType) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 256
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplate(String razorTemplate, Type templateType, Object model) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 127
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Parse(String razorTemplate, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag, String cacheName) in c:\_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line 435
   at ElmahR.Core.Plugins.<BuildPlugins>b__a(<>f__AnonymousType2`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier6)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ElmahR.Core.StartupConnection.<.ctor>b__1(IConnection c, IRequest r, String cid, String d)
   at ElmahR.Core.StartupConnection.OnReceived(IRequest request, String connectionId, String data)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.<>c__DisplayClassa.<>c__DisplayClassc.<ProcessRequest>b__7()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(Func`1 func)<---
```

Any idea what might be configured incorrectly for it to throw this error?  Is is something I need to change with Razor?

This is what I see:

[image: ElmahR Error]

Comment: The error is  most likely occurring while preparing the plugins, to be sure I suggest you go into your App_Data folder and from there remove the Plugins folder, and try what happens then. If that solves the issue (but you'll loose the piechart) then we can better target the problem, which might be of versioning nature.

Comment: Well this did allow the dashboard to finish loading.  Now I just don't see any of the errors in the apps though.  Is that because I'm not using MemoryErrorLog?  We use SqlErrorLogs.  Thanks for the wonderful work @Wasp. I hope I can get this working sufficiently.

Comment: Did you add the ElmahR.Elmah.ErrorPostModule in your monitored app? You can still use the other ELMAH modules, so there's no problem if you keep on persisting them with SqlErrorModule, but you need to add the one I mentioned to have the errors posted to the dashboard, and configure it properly.

Comment: Well I installed the ElmahR.Elmah nuget package in the monitored app.  The errorPost targetUrl value is `http://localhost/ElmahR/posterror.axd`

Comment: And that's the url of your dashboard? That url must point to where the dashboard is, because it's where the errors are sent.

Comment: That is the URL of the dashboard.  I thought it might show legacy errors, but the dashboard only shows new errors?  The trick to get new errors to show was to remove this attribute from the errorPost that gets set by the nuget install: `secret="SECRET_PASSPHRASE_(SPECIFY_JUST_IN_CASE_OF_ENCRYPTED_POST)"`. Thanks for your time on this.  Any idea how I can get the Pie chart working or is that not possible with Razor v3?

Comment: Yep, there are some default values to twaak :) To persist errors on ElmahR you have to use one of the Persistence modules, also illustrated in the docs. There's no way so far to see historical errors stored in ELMAH stores, they must be in ElmahR stores managed by Persistence modules.

Comment: About Razor v3, you might try updating the references in the dashboard and specifying v3 in the appsettings, but I never tried it so far. I know I'm a bit behind with new pieces appeared recently, but I'm into other things now and ElmahR has to wait a bit...